# What should I have my dehumidifier set at to dry out my basement?

Tags: basement, humidity

I have a 1600 sq ft home. The wellmate sprung a leak last Sat and soaked the basement. Im running fans down there and just got a 40 pint dehumidifier per the service guy. What setting should I set it. I have central air. I don't want basement to mold. I had it at 50 just put it on 45.

Answer (score 3):

Humidity levels between 40-50% are what most people prefer in a house. So, I'd say that setting is fine. If you live in a humid region, you may want to keep the dehumidifier running down there all the time (and set it up to drain via a hose rather than having to constantly empty the bucket)

Comment: Just keep in mind, if you drain a dehumidifier via a drain line it could potentially run continuously. You'd be surprised how much electricity a dehumidifier can suck up.

Comment: True, though I come from the land of humidity where it's normal to have a dehumidifier running continuously in basements.

Answer (score 0):

I just up sized to a 75 pint it works wonderfully. Keeps our basement around 1400 sq feet, at 45% without running all the time. 50 Pint should work but will run more then a bigger one.My opinion, when you can look at a 75 pt. would serve you better in the long run using less power for the size of the area your using it.